# How to add a total to a chart in google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to add a total of the amounts to the chart below.

https://jsfiddle.net/porterhouse47/6e0ejxLb/

I created a function to sum the values and you can see that it's correct if you uncomment the alert. I tried adding a new row for the total as you can see at the bottom but it doesn't show.

```js
// Load Charts and the corechart/bar char package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});

// Draw the pie chart for the Total Costs when Charts is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);

// Draw the pie
function drawPieChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Dollars'],
    ['Canada', 12250000],
    ['USA', 22750000]
  ]);

  function getSum(data, column) {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++)
      total = total + data.getValue(i, column);
    return total;
  }

  //alert(getSum(data, 1));


  // In order to show currency correctly
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    negativeColor: 'red',
    negativeParens: true,
    pattern: '$###,###'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var options = {
    title: "North America 2017",
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage',
    slices: {
      0: {
        color: '#328213'
      },
      1: {
        offset: 0.1,
        color: '#57a33a'
      },
    },
    pieStartAngle: 70,
    width: 400,
    height: 300
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('total_costs_pie'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
  addRow('Total', getSum(data, 1));
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>

<body>
  <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
  <table class="columns">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="total_costs_pie" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have maby solution for you:

**HTML:**

```
</script>

<body>
  <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
  <table class="columns">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="total_costs_pie" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="total"></td>
      <td id="number"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
// Load Charts and the corechart/bar char package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});

// Draw the pie chart for the Total Costs when Charts is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);

// Draw the pie
function drawPieChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Dollars'],
    ['Canada', 12250000],
    ['USA', 22750000]
  ]);

  function getSum(data, column) {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++)
      total = total + data.getValue(i, column);
    return total;
  }

  //alert(getSum(data, 1));


  // In order to show currency correctly
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    negativeColor: 'red',
    negativeParens: true,
    pattern: '$###,###'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var options = {
    title: "North America 2017",
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage',
    slices: {
      0: {
        color: '#328213'
      },
      1: {
        offset: 0.1,
        color: '#57a33a'
      },
    },
    pieStartAngle: 70,
    width: 400,
    height: 300
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('total_costs_pie'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
  //function for addRow.....
  function addRow (name, number) {
    //add name and number to .total
    total_name = document.createTextNode(name + number);
    total.appendChild(total_name);
  }
  addRow('Total: ', getSum(data, 1));
}
```

i added function for your addRow. And new tr and td to embed this atributes. I hope thats help you or give you path to do something like this ;)

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing that out. Is there any way to have the total be inside the chart itself? Right now the total appears outside of the chart body.

Comment: You can try to style it with css, so i mean position, color, size etc. This is fastest way for me. You can try adding this total and number to var options with this function. So.. for me best way is css (easiest way :P)